# What is called a library that allows emulation of a browser for automating purposes?

Tags: python, html, clojure, web, automation

I have an automating task in which I need to fill several forms in a site with data from word documents. For that I would need a library that emulates a browser and allows me to programatically enter a site and access html elements. What is this called? Are there examples of libraries that do this for python or clojure?

Comment: What you describe is called a headless browser.

Comment: [requests](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) may be helpful.

Comment: The general term "HTML scraping" or "Web scraping". Depending on the site, you may or may not be able to do it with a mere HTML parser and an HTTP client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of choices:

1. [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)
2. [Selenium](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium/)

There are others too, but I can't remember them off the top of my head right now (will post as and when I remember more)

Comment: There is a Selenium wrapper for Clojure that served me.

Answer (score 4):

You may wanna take a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) too:

> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit with JavaScript API. It has fast and
>   native support for various web standards: DOM handling, CSS selector,
>   JSON, Canvas, and SVG.

If you just want to submit a form, it would probably be easier to forge a request and send it using [urllib2](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

In nowadays **Clojure**, [http-kit](https://github.com/shenfeng/http-kit) is my favorite. It just makes http interaction very easy.

```
; taken from github
(defn on-response [resp]
  ;; {:status 200 :body "....." :headers {:key val :key val}}
  (println resp))

;;; initialize, timeout is 40s, and default user-agent
 (http/init :timeout 40000 :user-agent "http-kit/1.1")

;;; other params :headers :proxy binary? keyify?
(http/get {:url "http://shenfeng.me" :cb on-response})

;;; other params :headers :proxy binary? keyify?
(http/post {:url "http://example/"
        :cb on-response
        :body {"name" "http-kit" "author" "shenfeng"}  :binary? true})
```

I have also used [CasperJs](http://casperjs.org/) and it just makes any headless browsing possible. Also, you can interact with the client side javascript while automating the browsing. 
The only draw back I found was that it was slightly harder to integrate all this with existing code, but as a standalone tool it was perfect. It also supports both coffescript and javascript scripting.

Look at the [Quickstart](http://casperjs.org/quickstart.html) to get an idea on how it works.